# The fan rotates at a high speed and the system does not boot

Tags: dual-boot, display-resolution, intel-graphics, intel, fan

I know this can't be OS related completely, but maybe a solution can be provided for it. I connected a broken vga cable to my dual boot system
The problem was that the vga cable was broken and Ubuntu could not give me the resolution of 1920x1080 (it offered a lower one), but Windows was fine and gave the original resolution.

I changed the vga cable and used the previous one (even though it had a connection). The 1920x1080 resolution reappeared in Ubuntu, but this time when we go back to Windows, Windows gets confused and always starts with the famous blue screen (your pc ran...)  It will restart the system.
This continued until (maybe 5 reboots) the system would no longer boot
And it is like that after turning on, after 30 seconds the fan starts rotating at a high speed and nothing happens!
It has been like this since yesterday. I left the system alone for about 1.5 hours but nothing happened.  After a day I turned it back on and after turning the fan back on it spins horribly at very high rpm.

My system is a hp compaq elite 8200 with 1TB hard disk drive, 512GB intel ssd and 16GB RAM.  I hope the problem is clear enough

Comment: Sounds like your question is actually about Windows.

Comment: sudo apt install lm-sensors

Comment: update the question indicating when the problem starts (Windows, Grub, Ubuntu),  whether the VGA cable is plugged in still, and whether the laptop display is used.  The way this reads, the laptop is powered on while plugged into VGA, nothing gets displayed, and the fan is at 100%.  My response to that would be unplug the VGA cable.